# What is the difference between "an essay on something" and "an essay in something"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, formality

In most cases you write "an essay on something" but recently I came across some "essays in something"

Is there a difference in meaning? Is the "in" more formal?

Comment: Also *book in* versus *book on*. If you run a [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=book+in+philosophy%2C+book+on+philosophy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), and look at the instances, you will see that there are many cases where people talk about a "book in philosophy" rather than a "book on philosophy." Looking at the search results, I can't see that there is any real difference in meaning. Certainly, some people would never use the preposition *in* in this context.

Comment: @Peter: the problem with Ngrams is that you never know whether it is genuinely used as a phrase. E.g, I would *never* say 'book in philosophy', but may well have sent an e-mail saying "I read that book in Philosophy of Science", which would register.

Comment: @TimLymington: [Perhaps his scattered thoughts about time and history would have been pulled into a more substantial framework had he ever been able to write the systematic, substantial book in philosophy which he desired.](http://books.google.com/books?id=wLoKfdx7-3QC&pg=PA48&dq=%22book+in+philosophy%22&hl=en&ei=3EVKTtWUGYGWtwfx8LG8Cg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CEwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22book%20in%20philosophy%22&f=false) At the bottom of the Ngram, there's a link that lets you see some of the results. This is from one of these, and the majority of hits are using it this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred way to introduce the scope, subject or topic of the essay is "an essay on *something*". Sometimes *in* is used but it's quite uncommon and "an essay in ..." has several other uses. For example:

> **publication** "In a recent essay in *the journal Nature*..."
>   **subject** "...a most influential essay in *speculative thought*"
>   **style**  "students who wrote their essay in *cursive*..."
>   **year of publication** "In your Harper's essay in *1996*, you promised that..."

Comment: **subject** with "in" would be the same meaning as with "on", wouldn't it.

Comment: You don't seem to realise that your second example uses a different sense of the word 'essay'.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases, *an essay in...* doesn't mean a written work at all.  The original meaning was 'an attempt' (from the French, I would guess), and so *my first essay in carpentry* could be a shelf, whereas *my first essay on carpentry* is probably telling other people how to put up shelves.

Comment: I'm glad someone pointed this out.

Answer (score 0):

An essay "on" something has that thing as its topic. An essay "in" something has that thing a its publication medium.

> I read an essay in *The New Yorker*
>   I wrote an essay on punctuation.

Comment: I ran a google ngram--I think "in" is used a litle more widely than just a print medium.

Comment: @simchona: That doesn't prove they are used to mean the same thing, if that's what you're implying.

Comment: People definitely talk about a *book in* and an *essay in* various fields (philosophy, history, anthropology). Google Ngrams seems to show relatively few instances of this when the field is in the hard sciences, although I could be misinterpreting the data. I don't believe there's any difference between a *book in* and a *book on* a field, but I can't say for sure.